# Can't instantiate a new GattDeviceService

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to Bluetooth LE, and I'm trying to write to a Bluetooth HID device.

I'm using Visual Studios 2015 and am building a WPF application.

currently my code looks like this:

```
var hidDevices = await DeviceInformation
    .FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(
        GattServiceUuids.HumanInterfaceDevice));

GattDeviceService bleDevice = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(hidDevices[0].Id);
```

I have some code after, but my code stops right after I try to create a new `GattDeviceService`.

I know `hidDevices[0]` is occupied, but the ID generated shows up like this:

> `\\?/BTHLEDEVICE#{00001812-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}_Dev_VID&.........`

I'm curious if that is normal.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I throw this exception:

A device attached to the system is not functioning.(Exception from HRESULT:0x8007001F).

I throw this even if I'm connected to the Bluetooth LE device.

Answer (score 0):

GATT API does not allow you access HID Services.

I found information about your problems:
**Bluetooth GATT**—Windows.Device.Bluetooth.Gatt

- The API lets Windows Store app developers implement GATT client
  profiles for collecting data from low energy (LE) sensors.
- A Bluetooth 4.0 radio is required to use the GATT API.
- **The GATT API prevents access to the following in-box and invalid
  services:**
  (Bluetooth SIG name) 0x1812 HID Over GATT Service

For more informations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182882.aspx